# Selenium Click Image Link based on Alt (including quote)

Tags: java, selenium

I have a tricky one!

I am trying to test an image button click in Selenium. This is the HTML code:

```
<a href="/targetPage.do?status=onOrder&"><img src="/img/buttons/showOnOrder.gif" alt="Show 'On Order'"/></a>
```

I completely agree that having the single quote in the alt text is not ideal/good, but for the purposes of this test, I can't currently change the code.

I have tried the following

```
selenium.click("//img[@alt=\"Show 'On Order'\"]");
selenium.click("xpath=//img[@alt='Show ''On Order''']");
```

But no joy. Please, please, please make my day and suggest the syntax I can use that works.

Comment: "//img[@alt=\"Show 'On Order'\"]" seems to be correct and works for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
selenium.click("//a[contains(@href,'onOrder')]/img");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
selenium.click("//img[contains(@alt,'Show') and contains(@alt,'On Order')]");

or

selenium.click("xpath=//img[@alt='Show \'On Order\'']");

or

selenium.click("css=img[alt*='Show'][alt*='On Order']");
```